# Residuals sum of squared for multiple imputation using mice package in R

Tags: r, r-mice

With the `mice` package, how do we check for the residuals sum of squared of the pooled analysis?

```
library(mice) 
imp <- mice(nhanes, seed = 24500)
fit <- with(imp, lm(chl ~ age + bmi))
pool(fit)
summary(pool(fit))
```

`fit` contains the analysis for each input dataset and `pool(fit)` the pooled results. Is there a command to check the residuals sum of squared for a standard `lm` object, something like `residuals(pool(fit))`?

Comment: For my above posted example i assumed MCAR assumption for my data analysis. anyone can tell this analysis commands is for MCAR or MAR? Am i doing rite analysis under MCAR?

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the residuals for each of the input dataset with the function
res= sapply(fit[[4]],residuals)

and one option (although I don't think it's been published anywhere) is to average the residuals over the multiple imputed datasets, 
apply(res,1,mean)